# Зачем нужен this параметр произвольного типа?

Tags: c++, классы

При указании `this` параметра [можно](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:3,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:3,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27struct+A+%7B%0A++void+foo(this+A+self)%3B+++//+OK%0A++void+bar(this+int+self)%3B+//+OK,+but+why%3F%0A%7D%3B%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27/std:c%2B%2Blatest%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x64+msvc+v19.latest+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) указать произвольный тип, а не только тип класса. Зачем это сделано? Как это можно использовать?

```
struct A {
  void foo(this A self);   // OK
  void bar(this int self); // OK, but why?
};
```

Comment: [Explicit object parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Explicit_object_parameter) — возможность из пока ещё не вышедшего C++23, поэтому в будущем возможно правила будут скорректированы. Но пока сами авторы пропосала [не считают полезной](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0847r7.html) конструкцию с неклассовым this-параметром: `These are even more unlikely to be actually useful code. ... We think these declarations can best be left for compilers to warn about if they so choose, rather than coming up with a language rule to reject them.`

Comment: @wololo правила уже утвердили и даже реализовали MSVC, так что к выходу С++23 они не изменятся, только если в будущих стандартах. Думаю, цитата относится к ситуации, когда нет преобразования к `int`, тогда `bar` нельзя вызвать. Но если добавить оператор преобразования, то вызвать можно. Интересно узнать о юзкейсах в таком случае.

Comment: https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2022/09/23/copy-on-write/

Comment: @wololo,  цитата рассмешила _ отлично сказано...